# Plot with multiple categorical predictors and before/after comparison

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

I have a dataset with 5 categorical variables that relate to before/after numerical data. I need to plot the relationship between the categorical data and the numerical results. Each category relates to a part of the research in which kind_of_measure is related to how the measure was taken, cause_variation_turb and associated_condit are descriptions of human impacts on water quality and kind_particle is the kind of particle that altered water quality. The numerical data (mean_turb_contr and mean_turb_antrop) are compared to show if there was an increase or decrease in turbidity and are used to assess if water quality increased or decreased.
Is there any way to plot all information in a single plot? I have plotted individual plots with before/ after bars but it gave me 5 plots that take too much space. I need to present as much data as possible in the least number of figures and I already have many figures, so it is essential to summarize my results. Any ideas on how can I do this? Is there any graphical way to join categorical variables showing their relation to before/ after information?

Here is an example of my data.

| kind_of_measure | cause_variation_turb | associated_condit | kind_particle | unit | mean_turb_contr | mean_turb_antrop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| repeat_time | dam_removal |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 39.24 | 211.19 |
| repeat_time | dam_removal |  | suspended_solids | NTU | 3.93 | 334.35 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 48.57 | 1405 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 103.8 | 203 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 162.7 | 1506.5 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 78.14 | 950.7 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 63.2 | 2285.7 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 50.92 | 1372.9 |
| repeat_time | sediment_washout | el_nino | suspended_solids | TSS | 54 | 25.2 |
| dif_places | deforestation |  | suspended_solids | NTU | 2.6 | 3 |
| dif_places | deforestation |  | suspended_solids | TSS | 4.2 | 5.8 |
| repeat_time | mining_dam_break | copper_gold | tailing | NTU | 0.29 | 116.54 |
| repeat_time | drought |  | algal_biomass | NTU | 2.87 | 9.11 |
| repeat_time | wetland_restoration | wastewater_effluent | suspended_solids | TSS | 3.16 | 9.46 |
| repeat_time | fire |  | ashes | TSS | 12.92 | 8.41 |
| dif_places | best_management_practices | cattle_grazing | suspended_solids | TDS | 382.32 | 251.22 |

Comment: Could you clarify whether the categorical variables are the predictors or the response?

Comment: Either way, I don't think there's a reasonable way to join these variables (there rarely is, whether categorical or continuous). Multiple panels in a single figure would be the standard solution.

Comment: The categorical variables are predictors. They´re a part of a survey about aquatic systems and are site descriptions and/ or causes for turbidity change (before/after comparison)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reasonable way to combine these into a single predictor (there rarely is). That said, with 5 categorical predictors and 2 continuous responses you have just 10 panels. 5 rows of 2 panels (or 2 rows of 5 panels) is quite reasonable if you do not have too many categories in each of the predictors.